# I get Amadeus Network Error at very simple requests. How to solve it?

Tags: amadeus, general-network-error

I am trying to use the Amadeus API

```
amadeus = Client(
    client_id=<my_id>,
    client_secret=<my_secret> )

response = amadeus.reference_data.locations.points_of_interest.get(
    latitude = 41.3926386,
    longitude = 2.16)
```

I only get the error: `amadeus.client.errors.NetworkError: [---]`

Last week this was working perfectly. Why now it is not working? Are madeus servers down?